# How to fix Class 'ZipArchive' not found in Excel export function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have excel export function in my report. It was working fine in my local server. But, export function was not working in my live server.

It shown error like

> Class 'ZipArchive' not found in
>   /libraries/koolreport/packages/excel/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php

Anyone can help me to find the solution for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [Zip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) library is required for `ZipArchive` to work. You have to install the php extension. If you're on Ubuntu or Debian, you can install the `php-zip` package. Restart your webserver afterwards.

Answer (score -4):

First of all, you must locate your third party classes in "vendor" directory on root path. For example;

- application
- system
- vendor
- index.php

You can do this easily with composer. If composer not installed on your system, you can download it on getcomposer.org

- In the terminal go to your project root folder
- Type "composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet"

The composer will automatically download it and create vendor path.

Now, you must create a custom library class with name is "Excel" in "application/library" path.

[Excel file content is here.](https://paste.laravel.io/07973432-216e-4623-bf33-0033cdae6c8d)

You can use it now in your controller file.

[Controller file content is here.](https://paste.laravel.io/1acdfe33-b80e-4c2a-9149-c4c0f20da95b)

Comment: This is not the problem here ZipArchive is a php module which needs installing in this case

Comment: Can you explain that further? Where does this `Excel` class come from?